# php - how to convert non utf-8 string to utf-8

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I've a php page that return a string in persian , this is the content I have now :

```
    ÙØ±ÙˆØ´Ú¯Ø§Ù‡ ØªØ¹Ø·ÛŒÙ„ Ù…ÛŒ Ø¨Ø§Ø´Ø¯ .
Ø³Ø§Ø¹Øª Ú©Ø§Ø±ÛŒ ÙØ±ÙˆØ´Ú¯Ø§Ù‡ 8 Ø§Ù„ÛŒ 22 
Ø±ÙˆØ²Ù‡Ø§ÛŒ Ø´Ù†Ø¨Ù‡ ØªØ§ Ù¾Ù†Ø¬ Ø´Ù†Ø¨Ù‡
```

as you can see, the encoding is wrong and it's not readable ,I need to convert it to utf-8 encoding . 
I'm returning the data from database, encoding of table and cell in database is     utf8_persian_ci  and it's shows currency in phpmyadmin .

How can I convert this non readable string to utf-8 encoding and make it readable ? 
I've tried utf8-encoding and below code but non of them works :

```
    echo iconv(mb_detect_encoding($string, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $string);
```

How can I fix this  ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this function:

```
public function content_iconv($data, $to = 'utf-8') {
    $encode_array = array('UTF-8','ASCII','GBK','GB2312','BIG5','JIS','eucjp-win','sjis-win','EUC-JP');
    $encoded = mb_detect_encoding($data, $encode_array);
    $to = strtoupper($to);
    if($encoded != $to) {
        $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'utf-8', $encoded);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use any conversion subroutines.  Fix the program.

The output is "Mojibake" for some Arabic text.  See the discussion of such [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .

For how to fix the data (unless you choose to reload it), see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases).